# How do I return Combinations using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, backtracking

I want to print the combinations of all the elements of a list. But every time my codes results in a list of empty lists. 
What is want is `input =  [1,2,3]` `Output = [[3],[1],[2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2],[]]`
What I am getting is `[[][][][][][][][]]`

`My Python code`

```
class Solution:
def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    result = []
    curNums = []
    def dfs(nums , i):
        if i == len(nums):
            result.append(curNums)
        else:
            curNums.append(nums[i])
            dfs(nums , i+1)
            curNums.pop()
            dfs(nums , i+1)
    dfs(nums , 0)
    return result
```

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/464882/8350440

Comment: In this case we need to use the `powerset` recipe from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `curNums` list you are appending is the same list every time - so the append/pop are all being made on the same list.

Instead what you need to append to the result should be a new copy of the list every time - try `result.append(curNums[:])`. Creating a copy of the current list values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations and create a permutation of each subset length? Something like this:

```
import itertools  
input =  [1,2,3]
results = []
for i in range(len(input)+1):
    results.append(list(itertools.permutations(input,i)))
```